# proftpd exit status 0 even when fails to start

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I wrote a small init script for proftpd (latest stable version, compiled myself) and am noticing that the executable exits with status 0 even if server fails to start (in my case, for example, due to SSH port conflict).

1. Shouldn’t it exit with > 0? Or,
2. How can a script detect whether startup was successful short of sleeping for arbitrary time and checking for PID?

> ```
> # ./proftpd
> # echo $? //returns 0
> ```

…but in /var/log/messages:

> Jan 27 12:20:15 staging3 proftpd[9103]: - Failed binding to 0.0.0.0,
>   port 22: Address already in use Jan 27 12:20:15 staging3
>   proftpd[9103]: - Check the ServerType directive to ensure you are
>   configured correctly.

Thanks
-nikita

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, if you can't rely one the return code, you have to check the PID (or to check if the port 22 is in use, or whatever other trick).

```
./proftpd &
echo 'the PID is ' $!
```

Comment: specific to ProFTPD, is it OK to check for pid as soon as ./proftp call returns, or do I have to sleep for an arbitrary amt of time? in other words, if proftpd is started successfully, is PID guaranteed to exist by the time proftpd exits?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was filed and addressed in ProFTPD; see [Bug#3752](http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3752).